# Creating a directory within a bundle during build

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, overlay, mkoverlay

I have a problem that seemed quite trivial to me, but since hours I don't get the clue: I need to have a directory within my app bundle that contains pictures (tiles for a map overlay). I need to iterate through that folder and the subfolders.

But how do I create a folder within the bundle (I mean the .app file) with Xcode? Any folder structures I have in the Finder or in Xcode won't make it into the app bundle (Xcode 4.2). I know it's possible to do so, because there is an example "TileMap" from the WWDC that does it the same way.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just import a folder with it's tree in Xcode, and when the import window ask you, choose:
"create folder reference for any added folders"        radio button...

this way that folder will be copied as it is in your main bundle app

Comment: Wow, that was quick - thanks a lot. I wasn't aware of that, works now!